# (this).parent().find('.classname') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I'm trying to have a click event where the user clicks a Div Question, then Jquery clones the Div Answer and displays it in a separate Div Clone.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/zNL63/2/

For some reason the following variable is coming back null. Any ideas?

```
 var answer = $(this).parent().find(".faq-answer").clone();
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var faqQuestion = $('.faq-question');
    var faqClone = $('.faq-clone');

    faqQuestion.click(function () {
        showAnswer();
    });

    faqClone.click(function () {
        hideAnswer();
    });

    function showAnswer() {
        $(".faq-clone").hide("slide");
        $('.faq-clone').html("");

        var answer = $(this).parent().find(".faq-answer").clone();
        $('.faq-clone').append(answer.html());
        $(".faq-clone").show("slide");
    }

    function hideAnswer() {
        $(".faq-clone").hide("slide");
        $('.faq-clone').html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: The referred element (this) is not being passed over to the functions. http://jsfiddle.net/zNL63/4/

Comment: Where is the point to clone an hidden element and show the clone ? http://jsfiddle.net/zNL63/11/

Comment: The Question/Answers are coming from a XML document through a VB loop. The desired effect is for the popup answer to be able to happen outside of the container holding the answer/question divs, so it seemed to be best to clone it into a separate div outside this container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would be to pass the handlers by reference:

```
faqQuestion.click(showAnswer);

faqClone.click(hideAnswer);
```

Now `this` inside of `showAnswer` and `hideAnswer` will be the clicked element.

Comment: I like your solution. +1

Comment: I understand now. Other answers seem to work, but this one seems best. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can not access element by $(this) within a function. You would need to pass that as a parameter.

Try:

```
function showAnswer(passedObject) {
    $(".faq-clone").hide("slide");
    $('.faq-clone').html("");

    var answer = passedObject.parent().find(".faq-answer").clone();
    $('.faq-clone').append(answer.html());
    $(".faq-clone").show("slide");
 }
```

and then you would use that function: `showAnswer($(this))`

or more logical & cleaner solution is what @Kevin B suggested.

Comment: I'm curious, though. How do jQuery functions like `show()` work?

Comment: @smerny that's not what I meant. I know how to use `show()`. I'm curious where I can find the source code for it. In other words, how does `show()` target the jQuery object you are doing it to?

Comment: @Jason I would assume that when you do object.show() you are calling that function on an object so it would have access to it.

Comment: @Jason, with this page in focus, hit ctrl+shift+j to open the javascript console... then type `$().show` and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

Make it even simplier, use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) jQuery function

**Is there any reason why you want to clone an hidden element and only show its clone**  ?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zNL63/11/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var faqQuestion = $('.faq-question');
    var faqClone = $('.faq-answer');
    faqQuestion.click(showAnswer);
    faqClone.click(hideAnswer);

    function showAnswer() {
        $(this).next('.faq-answer').show('slide');
    }

    function hideAnswer() {
        $(this).hide("slide");
    }
});
```

and apply to `.faq-answer` the `.faqClone` CSS

You could even produce short answer from a data-attribute :) to shorten even more HTML .

Comment: See my answer up on the original comment

Comment: @jessikwa thanks for the feed back, it makes sens :)